# I'm multiplying by 0 and not getting 0!!!! Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

IDLE:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> m = 1
>>> n//2*m//2
1
>>> n//2
2
>>> m//2
0
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here!?

Comment: multiplication and division have same precedence: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: What about `2*m//2`?

Comment: double // is floor division. 4 // 2 is equal to 4 / 2 since it is division without rest. 1 // 2 is not equal to 1 / 2, see my answer below

Answer (score 6):

Order of operations. Multiplication and division go left-to-right; it doesn't do all the division first and then the multiplication. So your expression expands like this:

```
n//2*m//2 = ((n//2)*m)//2 = ((4//2)*1)//2= (2*1)//2 = 2//2 = 1
```

If you want to take `n//2` and multiply it by `m//2`, you have to parenthesize it that way:

```
>>> n=4
>>> m=1
>>> (n//2)*(m//2)
#=> 0
```

Comment: this is not the question I believe, see my answer below

Comment: Perfect thanks. Is modulo also treated as a division operation?

Comment: Yes, it is. Python follows the usual algebraic order of infix operations, and modulus is the same precedence as multiplication and both division operators. See [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-summary).

Answer (score 0):

In python, multiplication and division carry the same weight and are therefore calculated from left to right. As a result of that, this is how Python reads your equation:

```
((4//2)*1)//2) = ((2)*1)//2) = ((2)//2) = 1
```